# is it possible to find dislikes on your own channel's video through youtube api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know that youtube is disabling dislikes, though is it still possible if you are the creator to view dislikes through youtube api?

Comment: In their press release, they said content creators can still view the number of dislikes. I'm not sure where it is shown though.  Here is the video where this is mentioned: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxOuG8jMIgI

Answer (score 0):

> **Creators: You’ll still be able** to find your exact dislike counts in
> YouTube Studio for each video–only if you’d like to. Creators will
> still be able to find their exact dislike counts in YouTube Studio if
> they would like to understand how their content is performing.

> **Developers:** If you’re using the YouTube API for dislikes, **you will no
> longer have access to public dislike data beginning on December 13th.**
> Your end users will still be able to view dislike data related to
> their **own content on authenticated API requests.** You can apply for an
> exemption (to have dislike data on non-authenticated calls) as long as
> you don’t display or share dislike data with your end users.

[The source](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/134791097/update-to-youtube-dislike-counts?hl=en)